# Shorten Member Function Scope Specifiers (Nested Classes) (C++)

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have nested classes as follows defined in a header file:

```
class ClassA 
{
  private:
    class ClassB 
    {
      private:
        int member_b;
      public:
        void function_name();
    };
};
```

In order to give a definition to the function "function_name()" in an external .cpp file, I have to access it like this:

```
void ClassA::ClassB::function_name()
{
  std::cout << member_b;
  return;
}
```

For the sake of this example, please do not ask why I'm using nested classes; I have a reason for doing so in my actual project.  However, my question is this; **is it possible to somehow shorten the** `ClassA::ClassB::function_name()` **in the implementation file to something like** `short::function_name()` **while still keeping the classes nested?**  I don't think that typedefs or new namespace definitions can help me here, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You can indeed use typedef here, see my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I should have mentioned, but ClassB still needs to remain private, as in my example.  Using typedefs doesn't seem to work unless ClassB is public, so is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualified type names allow you to define a typedef to represent a qualified class name. You can then use the typedef with the :: (scope resolution) operator to refer to a nested class or class member, as shown in the following example:

```
class outside
{
public:
      class nested
      {
      public:
            static int x;
            static int y;
            int f();
            int g();
      };
};
int outside::nested::x = 5;
int outside::nested::f() { return 0; };

typedef outside::nested outnest;       // define a typedef
int outnest::y = 10;                   // use typedef with ::
int outnest::g() { return 0; };
```

However, using a typedef to represent a nested class name hides information and may make the code harder to understand.

Source : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPSQF_9.0.0/com.ibm.xlcpp111.aix.doc/language_ref/cplr061.html

Comment: This works, but only if the nested class is public.  This wasn't something that I considered initially, but is it ONLY possible if that nested class is public?  Or can this still be done some other way if it's private/protected, as in my example?

Comment: You are right it works only when nested class is public.

Comment: So then is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for when the nested class is private?  I'm just wanting to shorten that long name for every function definition in the implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using aliases?

```
// C++11  
using fmtfl = std::ios_base::fmtflags;  
// C++03 equivalent:  
// typedef std::ios_base::fmtflags fmtfl;  

fmtfl fl_orig = std::cout.flags();  
fmtfl fl_hex = (fl_orig & ~std::cout.basefield) | std::cout.showbase | std::cout.hex;  
// ...  
std::cout.flags(fl_hex);
```

Code source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467695.aspx

Comment: I don't believe that this will work because the nested class is private.  Or am I wrong?